# IIS url rewrite one folder and subcontent to another domain with query string

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I have hosted on a blog on my windows IIS and moved to another hosting and I need to create IIS URL rewrite rile

My Old domain URL is

http://test.com/blog  and I need to redirect **/blog** and subpages request to http://newtest.com 
suppose someone access

http://test.com/blog/index.php/2018/12/07/test

I need to redirect to

http://newdomain.com/index.php/2018/12/07/test

Can somebody please help me.I  tried many URL rewrite rules but during redirect it redirect with **/blog** folder this folder  not exist on remote

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved by the below method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Blog redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/blog/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.spiderip.com/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```